# Young man from a tribe of falconers must stop a demonic invasion

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this series on Kindle Unlimited a few years back.

The main character and his brother were born into a small tribe of falconers and the book starts with them in a competition to collect eggs for the tribe. After the brothers attend a festival to sell off the eggs, one of the brothers (the antagonist) is encouraged to leave the tribe and venture off adventuring with a party he meets at the festival.  He falls in love with one of the member of the group before he is betrayed and I think sacrificed/turned into a demon.

His brother, the protagonist, returns to the tribe (I believe) before he finds out that he is the chosen one and embarks on an adventure with elves, dwarves, magic, and an impending demonic invasion that he must stop. He eventually becomes a great and powerful wizard king after his adventures end.

Some brief details I remember from the series is that a dwarven ally is gravely injured in a cave by the sea and pretends to die before telling that they are all daft and that it takes more than that to kill a dwarf. Also the dwarf puts a weed into one of the characters food that give severe stomach issues as a prank.

Comment: Hi, Lucas! Please see [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) to help improve this question. For starters, when did it seem to be from? Who was the target audience?

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: Well, Kindle Unlimited was launched in July 2014 so it can't be before then.

Comment: @nebogipfel keep in mind the book could be much older than that.